# Inject request URI RequestMapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm working on a stubbing tool where a user can provide a list of endpoints and their associated JSON response. The idea is they will include a config file containing URIs and a directory of all stubbed responses. So essentially the config file will include the list of URI's that typically would be set using `@RequestMapping` if this was being built for a specific use case. Is there a way to have Spring send a success response even if the associated `@RequestMapping` doesn't exist?

Something similar to a SQL query e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))
fun sendResponse() : ResponseEntity<String> {
   //Fetched correct response from interceptor
   return ResponseEntity<String>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer. You need to use `@RequestMapping(value = "/**", method = arrayOf(RequestMethod.POST))`.